# Git and other git subdirectories

Tags: git, github

I dont know if my problem is related to github or git or PyCharm...

I have a laptop (L) and a stationary PC 1 (= P1).

I've made a git repo on github, and I've worked a lot on it from my P1. Then commit + push all my work on github.

From L, I did a git clone, and it worked really well.

Now, I've added a new library in my Django `static/vendors` folder. It's called howler. I got it from [here](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js.git). I've added it using a `git clone https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js.git`. Same thing with another library called swiper: `git clone https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper.git`.

The problem is that PyCharm added the 2 git repositories in the vcs and they're not visible from my 'original' github remote: when I commit + push my work, everything is commited + pushed **except** those two libraries. From the PyCharm menu, if I do a VCS -> git -> Remotes, I get this:

[image: Git Remotes]

So, when I do a git pull from my laptop, it gets everything **except** those two libraries.
What should I do to add those repositories into my github repo, and then being able, from any other PC, to make a `git clone` then afterwards a `git pull`, and get those libraries too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes against the purpose of having packages. Best practice is to keep your source code in git, and the packages outside of it. If your source code has a list of required packages needed to run, you will have to install those packages whenever cloning the repo on a new machine.

Instead of using `git clone`, I would recommend using this command: `git submodule add https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js.git howler`

Using this submodule will create a *.gitmodules* file in your repo that will look like this:

```
[submodule "howler"]
    path = howler
    url = https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js.git
```

This will let you keep track of all the packages installed and being used in your project.

If you really need these packages in your repo. Delete the *.git* hidden folders in both the packages and then do a git add, commit, and push to the repo.

Comment: I had to do this to make it work: `git rm --cached static/vendors/swiper` and after this: `git submodule add https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js.git static/vendors/howler.js`

Answer (score 0):

Git is being smart about this and treating howler and swiper as not being part of your project, because you have cloned them. It treats it as being a submodule, but you probably don't have the `.gitmodules` file to handle that. You can do two things:

1. Use the subtrees as submodules. See docs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules
2. Or, the easy way: remove the `.git` directories in the howler and swiper subtrees. Then git will not see them as submodules anymore BUT you won't be able to git pull to keep them updated anymore.